# Constraints warning in console

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, warnings, ios-autolayout

I am new in Auto Layout and constraints. So I applied constraints according to super view by storyboard, but facing some below warning:

> "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.   Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try
>   this:         (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect;         (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint
>   or constraints and fix it.  (
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x14dfa550 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x14df81e0(0)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x14dfa520 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x14df81e0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14ed7ff0
>   )>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2016-08-01 11:56:48.694
>   Laatli[1034:623262] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2016-08-01 11:56:48.699
>   Laatli[1034:623262] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x14dfa550 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x14df81e0(64)]>",
>       "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x14dfa520 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x14df81e0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14ed7ff0
>   )>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful."

I don't know why these warnings are coming in console.

Comment: i think you have added more constraints than enough, and also one more thing is that do not use "Add missing constraints" option after you will get the error, try to resolve that constraint error.

Comment: @SuhasPatil But i didn't use add missing constraints.
Why these warnings are coming ,Because of more constraints ?

Comment: yeah, these are due to more constraints that are unwanted, Generally it happens when we have given top, left, right, bottom and with this constraints  if you provide height constraint to any object thenthere is change of getting such type of warnings

Comment: @SuhasPatil But if i will remove any constraint then i will not get the UI according to my requirement.

Comment: No, this not possible. You have to add the perfect constraints with your UI req. else you can ignore this warnings

Comment: @SuhasPatil I can ignore the warnings ,
But i want to add perfect constraints , i am new on that .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118773/discussion-between-suhas-patil-and-kishor0011).

Comment: @SuhasPatil Please Explain me if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unsatisfiable Layouts**

Unsatisfiable layouts occur when the system cannot find a valid solution for the current set of constraints. Two or more required constraints conflict, because they cannot all be true at the same time.

**Identifying Unsatisfiable Constraints**

Often, Interface Builder can detect conflicts at design time. ON these occasions, Interface builder displays the error in a number of ways:

- All the conflicting constraints are drawn on the canvas in red.
- Xcode lists the conflicting constraints as warnings in the issue
  navigator.
- Interface Builder displays a red disclosure arrow in the upper right
  corner of the document outline.

[image: Unsatisfiable Constraints]

Click the disclosure arrow to display a list of all the Auto Layout issues in the current layout.

Interface Builder can often recommend fixes for these issues. For more information, see [Resolving Layout Issues for a View Controller, Window, or Root View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/resolve_view_layout_issues_quickly.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014226-CH37) in [Auto Layout Help.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014226)

Below is the link where Apple has specified all of this. Please do read the documentation. It has most of the answers a beginner might want.

Source: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ConflictingLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH19-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

Explanation for this Error of console shown in xCode:-

"Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. ( "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x14dfa550 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x14df81e0(0)]>", "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x14dfa520 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x14df81e0] (Names: '|':UIView:0x14ed7ff0 )>", "", "", "", "", "" )

It means:-

**There is some extra constraints added to one view. Constraints related to vertical i.e. from Top you have given two constraints which is creating problem.**

It will automatically delete any constraint to satisfy condition.

**You need to delete any one constraints** and apply proper valid constraint to UIView.